# Phonegap App : Page layout breaks after input from keyboard

Tags: android, css, angularjs, cordova, phonegap-build

When user enters login details and next page loads,layout becomes as in below pic.

[image]

Whole app layout breaks and view comes down by the size of onscreen keyboard. This stays there unless u change the orientation or do tapping couple of times.

This happens only on login page because there is full screen image in background.
Below is the preference in my config.xml file

```
 <preference name="android-windowSoftInputMode" value="stateHidden|adjustResize"/>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use window.scrollTo(0.0); on the login click method .